# Angularjs array as style array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a little problem with a object array in AngularJS. I need to create an array with fixed lenght that contains object like this:

```
var obj = {
"background-color" : "FFFF"
}
```

Now I can achieve this result easily in javascript and I have created an array inside the angularjs controller

```
$scope.selected_colors = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
$scope.selected_colors.push(getRandomColor());
}
```

where getRandomColor() is a function that select a random color from a list. At this point in my web page I have a piece of code that renders a list of objects (I want each of them having a different background color):

```
<div class='card' ng-repeat='item in items'>
<div class='background' ng-style='selected_colors[$index]'>
...
</div>
</div>
```

But at this point no background is rendered. But if I create an object like that:

```
$scope.background = {
"background-color": "blue"
}
```

and if I use that in ng-style call I see the background. Is a problem with runtime generated objects? I'm missing something that makes this model work? Is there a better way to achieve this result in angularjs?

Comment: can you print/log the selected_colors array?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `getRandomColor()` just return a color string (eg: blue), that make `selected_colors[$index]` is a color string but `ng-style` expect an object so your code doesn't work. To fix this, you just need to change your code to:

```
...
$scope.selected_colors.push({"background-color": getRandomColor()});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, was an error in declaring the color for a missing # in front of the hexadecimal code that was missing in building the color code string. I left the question up if someone needs a hint to perform the same operation in the future.

Thank you all.